# Website no VS Community 2017

Tags: aplicação-web, visual-studio

Eu baixei a nova versão do VS Community 2017 e fiquei um pouco confuso quanto a iniciar um novo website. 
Lembro que antes ia em File > New Website (abaixo de New Project). Agora não mais.

Quando escolho New Project, estando em Visual C# vejo a opção Web, porém apenas ASP.NET Core Web Application e ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework). Qual dos dois seria exatamente o intuito?
Nesta mesma parte do menu em Web, abaixo tem a opção Previous Versions que contém o antigo ASP.NET Empty Website.

O VS foi mudado desta forma de criar websites? Estou meio que perdido no tempo mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Obs: Todo o texto foi retirado na integra do artigo Conceitos -  .NET Framework versus .NET Core (José Carlos Macoratti- link http://www.macoratti.net/16/11/net_framcore1.htm)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O .NET Framework é usado para desenvolvimento de aplicações Windows usando Windows Forms , WPF e de aplicações Web usando ASP .NET MVC.
- O .NET Core é open-source e multiplataforma e suporta UWP e as bibliotecas da ASP .NET Core. A UWP é usada para criar aplicação Windows 10 e a ASP .NET Core é usada para criar aplicações Web para Windows, Linux e Mac.
- O Xamarin é um framework que permite criar aplicações nativas para Android, iOS e Windows Phone.

Podemos agrupar e comparar as principais características do .NET Core e do .NET Framework conforme mostra a tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comparando as características entre os dois Frameworks podemos fazer algumas considerações quanto a escolher qual framework usar para iniciar o desenvolvimento de um projeto.

Considere usar o .NET Framework levando em conta os seguintes fatores:

Você não vai necessitar de um suporte multiplataforma para sua aplicação;

Você precisa de um ambiente estável;

Você precisa realizar atualizações frequentes;

Você já esta trabalhando em um aplicativo que a .NET Framework e vai estender suas funcionalidades;

Você já possui  um equipe com experiência na .NET Framework;

Você precisa do suporte ao Visual Basic

Você vai criar aplicações desktop Windows Forms ou WPF

Você vai desenvolver aplicações ASP .NET Web Forms

Você precisa usar os recursos do WCF , WF e Worflow Services

Você tem receio de novidades;

Considere usar o .NET Core se:

Você deseja segmentar suas aplicações nos sistemas operacionais Windows, Linux e Mac;

Você esta disposto a realizar ajustes e atualizações visto que o .NET Core ainda não é maduro;

Você esta disposto a aprender coisas novas e quer estar na vanguarda;

Quando eu não devo usar ou migrar para o .NET Core ?

A sua aplicação atual esta em produção e usa o .NET Framework

Você já iniciou o desenvolvimento de uma grande projeto corporativo

Você vai precisar de recursos estáveis do Entity Framework 6, WCF e WorkFlow Foundation

E quando usar o Xamarin ao invés do .Net Core ?

Se você quer obter o melhor desempenho e uma interface de usuário agradável, o caminho a percorrer é "nativo", onde Xamarin é uma das opções, bem como Objective-C/Swift e Java. Mas, se você precisa atingir pelo menos duas plataformas (iOS e Android), então Xamarin é pode ser a melhor escolha possível para a criação de aplicações nativas multiplataforma.

Nota:  Existe também o Xamarin Forms que permite criar aplicações nativas para várias plataformas. Ele fornece um Kit de ferramentas multiplataforma com páginas.

E se eu desejar portar aplicações .NET Framwork para .NET Core ?

Neste caso consulte a documentação que explica processo neste link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/index